# Why i can't add the value to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I tried to made an app to get result from gmaps API.

I want to use array list to save the result from `JSONObject`
The log from `result_name.toString()` return the correct array, 
but the log from `result_phone.toString()` is empty.

I'm confused because the res value is correct. `checkEmptyJsonResponse` is a class that i created to check whether or not the value for international_phone_number is empty JSON response.
It returns either the JSON Value or "Not Available"

```
String res = checkEmptyJsonResponse(result,"international_phone_number");
```

In this case, if i put Log to see the value of res, it return the correct value.

It seems that something wrong in result_phone.add(res) but i don't know what

What did i do wrong?

---

Here is the part of my code that i use
**FragmentOne.java**

```
ArrayList<String> result_name = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> result_address = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> result_placeid = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> result_phone = new ArrayList<String>();

public void getLocation(String tipe_instansi){
    final AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    final StringBuilder[] googlePlacesUrl = {new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?")};
    googlePlacesUrl[0].append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
    googlePlacesUrl[0].append("&rankby=prominence");
    googlePlacesUrl[0].append("&radius=" + PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
    googlePlacesUrl[0].append("&type="+tipe_instansi);
    googlePlacesUrl[0].append("&sensor=true");
    googlePlacesUrl[0].append("&key=AIzaSyCtaLQPSPN2SwGM2cr_itZIkWG0sjQJ7uc");
    Log.d("URL : ", googlePlacesUrl[0].toString());


    client.get(googlePlacesUrl[0].toString(), new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            if(responseBody!=null){
                try {
                    JSONObject array = new JSONObject(new String(responseBody));
                    JSONArray result = array.getJSONArray("results");

                    for(int i=0; i<result.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject get_result = result.getJSONObject(i);

                        result_name.add(get_result.getString("name"));
                        result_address.add(get_result.getString("vicinity"));
                        result_placeid.add(get_result.getString("place_id"));

                        Log.d("PLACE ID : ", result_placeid.get(i).toString());

                        googlePlacesUrl[0] = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?");
                        googlePlacesUrl[0].append("placeid=" + result_placeid.get(i).toString());
                        googlePlacesUrl[0].append("&key=AIzaSyCtaLQPSPN2SwGM2cr_itZIkWG0sjQJ7uc");

                        Log.d("URL2 : ", googlePlacesUrl[0].toString());

                        client.get(googlePlacesUrl[0].toString(), new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject array = new JSONObject(new String(responseBody));
                                    JSONObject result = array.getJSONObject("result");

                                    String res = checkEmptyJsonResponse(result, "international_phone_number");
                                    result_phone.add(res);

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to Get Phone Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    for(int k = 0; k<result.length(); k++){
                        Log.d("RESULTZZ - ", "Name : "+result_name.get(k)+ " Address : "+result_address.get(k));
                    }
                    Log.d("RESULTZZZ - ", result_name.toString());
                    Log.d("RESULTZZZZZZ - ", result_phone.toString());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "responseBody Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failure to Connect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I guess the logging of `res` happens after printing `result_phone.toString()` i.,e it is processed asynchronously

Comment: @user7 so, what should i do? Since i'm new, what should i do to wait those async task to finish?

Comment: You have added your phone number to list in a callback. There is a possibility that your log statement of phone number executing before your phone number list being populated.

Comment: are you getting any exceptions?

Answer (score -1):

It's because you call `result_phone.add(res);` from second **ASYNC** request (it just launched, but will be complete later, not now), so when `Log.d("RESULTZZZZZZ - ", result_phone.toString());` called in first request's callback - there are no results yet.

Comment: oh my god. I just realize my code is working from the beginning. I tried to postDelayed it for 5 sec and boom, it appears.
What should i do to wait the asynctask to finish? What code should i use?

Comment: You need to call some `processResult` method after second callback will be finish. In this method you can work with all your lists: `result_name, result_address, result_placeid, result_phone `

Comment: he is calling` result_phone.add(res);` at correct place that is in OnSuccess

Comment: @ZaidMirza yes, @user8989957 added result in correct place - `onSuccess`, but line `Log.d("RESULTZZZZZZ - ", result_phone.toString());` called to early, before second *async* request will complete, so item is not added yet.
@user8989957 should do *work* in second `onSuccess` method, that was I say before